# Is there a workaround to avoid iframes in selenium testing?

Tags: python, selenium, iframe

I am testing complex and non-public webpages with `python-selenium`, which have interconnected iframes.

To proper click on a button or select some given element in a different iframe I have to switch to that iframe . Now, as contents of the pages might reload to the correct iframe I constantly have to check if the correct iframe is loaded yet, otherwise I have to go back to the default content, do the check again etc.

I find this completely annoying and user-unfriendly behavior of selenium.

Is there a basic workaround to find e.g. an element in ANY iframe? Because I do not care about iframes. I care about elements...

Comment: iframe is not a problem with the selenium. it is a problem of your application uses multiple frame. But selenium gives option to handle the frame and values.

Comment: But its annoying to deal with it... from my experience anyway...

Comment: It may be design issue of your web application page. If you use the page object model or page factory it wouldn't be a issue.

Comment: I have a webpage with an iframe which in itself contains an iframe. I have to deal with this setup. This setup cannot be changed. I have to work with this setup. The setup is fixed. 

My question was about to avoid changing iframes in selenium. It looks not well-thought from the side of selenium. Because as a user on the GUI I just can 'click'. Why can't I do the same in selenium...?

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately, no, there’s no way around this.

For context, this is likely not simply a limitation of Selenium alone, but of the WebDriver specification and, ultimately, modern browsers. Selenium merely implements the WebDriver specification, which in turn is limited by the features exposed by modern browsers. And browsers likely have good reasons for preventing you from doing this.

What you think of as a single page is actually comprised of multiple *documents*:

1. the *root* document, whose URL and title you see in your browser chrome, and
2. one or more embedded (or *child*) documents, for which an `<iframe>` element is really just a kind of “mount point.”

While the utility of being able to transparently traverse across document boundaries (as easily as one might traverse across a file system mount point) is obvious, browsers likely have their reasons for blocking it.

Not the least of these, I suspect, is to prevent cross-site scripting (XSS) attacks. That is, just because the browser user has the ability to view an embedded document, doesn’t mean a script in the parent document should be able to “see” into it. And allowing traversal from the parent into the child (via, e.g., `find_element_by_xpath`), would likely require that.

(Another reason, I imagine, is that most modern browsers isolate each document in a separate process, making traversal across their respective DOMs a far more complicated feature to implement.)

## Easing the burden with [capybara-py](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/capybara-py)

Given that one must switch contexts in order to search for and interact with elements in other documents, you can make it easier on yourself by adopting [capybara-py](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/capybara-py). It’s a layer on top of Selenium that provides (among many other things) simple context managers for switching between frames and windows:

```py
from capybara.dsl import page

with page.frame("name-of-child-frame"):
    page.click_link("The label of a link inside the child frame")
page.assert_text("Some text that is now expected to appear in the parent document")
```

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately the API is built that way and you can't do anything about it. Each IFrame is a separate document as such, so eventually search a object in every IFrame would mean Selenium has to switch to every IFrame and do that for you.

Now you can build a workaround by storing the IFrame paths and using helper methods to automatically switch to that IFrame hierarchy in your code. Selenium won't help you here, but you can ease your pain by writing helper methods designed as per your needs